# how to get number of days since a file was created in python

Tags: python, datetime

I need to get the number of days since a file was created, and i tried this code:

```
import os.path, time
import datetime
from datetime import date

path = 'D:/Reg.txt'

creation_date = "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(path))

today = datetime.datetime.today()

delta = today - creation_date

print(delta.days)
```

but i get this error message: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Comment: yes, I think so. `creation_date` is a str type. what exactly are you try to do though?

Comment: @rv.kvetch thanks for your quick respond, i need to get the number of days since the file was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `creation_date` was a string. To make it workable, convert it to a datetime object using the `datetime.fromtimestamp(epochtime)` from `datetime` library. Example below:

```py
import os.path, time
import datetime
from datetime import date

path = 'D:/Reg.txt'

creation_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(path))

today = datetime.datetime.today()

delta = today - creation_date

print(delta.days)
```

Note that `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` converts a number to a datetime object so you just need to pass in the epoch time directly. In your case, this was `os.path.getctime(path)`

Answer (score 0):

You should convert creation date into datetime format from string

```py
import os.path, time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

path = 'D:/Reg.txt'

creation_date = "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(path))

creation_date=datetime.strptime(creation_date, '%m-%d-%Y').date()

today = datetime.datetime.today()

delta = today - creation_date

print(delta.days)
```

Comment: i get this error: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: from datetime import datetime , add this line too